# Am having or have in this case

Tags: present-continuous

Imagine I am trying to connect  my smartphone to the net. The problem is that I am sitting in a train and the connection is not working .

What can I say " I **am having** difficulties to be connected to the net or **have** difficulties to be connected to the net."

I think the first one is better because it is not working now but should be later. the connection is supposed to work in a train where it is written Wifi .

Comment: You want the "present continuous":  "I am having difficulties connecting to the network."  This is a state you are in currently, and it is continuing into the future.  The time focus of the sentence is "now".

Comment: I'd also use singular - 'having difficulty'.

Comment: "having difficulties" would imply multiple problems, e.g. it took you a long time to connect then you found out you had no data allowance and your battery ran out.

Comment: **have difficulty connecting to the Internet**. No to + passive infinitive after "have difficulties"

Answer (score 1):

"Difficulty" is followed by a gerund, not an infinitive. But you are correct that you should use the present continuous here:

> I am having difficulties connecting to the net.

Answer (score -1):

As others have commented, you should say "...connecting to the net".

"I have difficulty/difficulties..." suggests that, right now or as a general rule,  a personal issue, for example your arthritis, prevents you.

"I have a problem" suggests that, right now or as a general rule, something external prevents you, for example there is no network signal.

"I have problems" suggests that, right now or as a general rule, there are multiple external factors that are preventing you.

"I am having problems" suggests that, over the recent past there are multiple external factors preventing you, or one factor that keeps recurring, and you expect them to continue in the near future.

"I have been having problems" suggests that for some time now, (either continuously, or intermittently) one or more issues have prevented you. For multiple issues, they may have all occurred at once, or maybe different problems on each occasion. If it's not followed by a "but" clause, the listener can assume that you expect the situation to continue for the foreseeable future.

Comment: It's very common to use "difficulty" with technical issues, and certainly doesn't imply personal/health issues. "Technical difficulties" is a common phrase for unspecified issues ("having trouble" is another option.)

Comment: @Stuart F Certainly If you specify "technical difficulties" that's certainly true, but "I am having difficulty...." is a different kettle of fish.